# How do I get custom fields of User on graphQL?

Tags: craft3, users, query, custom-field, graphql

I am wanting to fetch queries for custom fields of users, how would I go about doing that?

So if I did something like this:

```
query {
users {
        id
    firstName
    lastName
    email
    photo {
      id
    }       
}
```

}

How would I get the custom fields I created for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Users query](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#the-users-query) will return a list of `UserInterface` objects ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#the-userinterface-interface)) so you will need to do something like this:

```
query {
  users {
    ... on User {
      firstName
      lastName
      email
      photo {
        id
      }
      yourCustomField
      yourOtherCustomField
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect.